# How to search SubString in FullText index column?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to search substring in my FullText index column.

My table struture is : **child_table**

```
clustering_key int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
Parent_id char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',    
child_id char(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',    
data text,    
PRIMARY KEY (clustering_key),    
UNIQUE KEY child_index (child_id) USING BTREE,    
FULLTEXT KEY data_index (data),    
CONSTRAINT FK_child_table_parent_table FOREIGN KEY (Parent_id) REFERENCES parent_table (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE )    
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Let assume sample data is :

[image]

Some cases i observed :

**Case 1:**  When i used this pattern in my query ***MATCH (data) AGAINST ('xy*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)*** return 1 row

**Case 2:** When i used this pattern in my query ***MATCH (data) AGAINST ('zy*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)*** return 2 row

**Case 3:** When i used this pattern in my query ***MATCH (data) AGAINST ('*y*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)*** then no rows returned but I expected it to return both rows.

I think used (*) as prefix its not working.

Please help me find a solution for this issue.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct behaviour. From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html):

> The asterisk serves as the truncation (or wildcard) operator. Unlike the other operators, it is appended to the word to be affected. Words match if they begin with the word preceding the * operator.

In other words, the `*` can only be used at the end of a word as in your first two cases (`xy*` and `zy*`). If you want to use wildcard matching on both ends of the word, you would need to use `LIKE` or perhaps `RLIKE` e.g.

```
WHERE data LIKE '%y%'
```

Comment: Hi @Nick, I am using FullText Index on column for avoiding all row scan. When i used **LIKE** then this query scan all rows.

Comment: @Shubham unfortunately that is true. But an index can't work with a wildcard at the beginning of the string anyway.

Comment: you are right FullText index on column is useless if i used wildcard at the beginning of string . Please suggest you have any idea about how to search substring in large amount of data column with minimum row scan or how to overcome of the problem of current table structure.

Comment: @Shubham I'm afraid I don't think there is an answer to that question and without understanding exactly what information is in your `data` column it is hard to make suggestions as to how to improve the table structure.